# Writing captions automatically looking up tables or vectors

Tags: captions, loops

I am asking this question because I have not been able to find anything that goes straight to the point.

Let's imagine that we want to automatize graph depiction in Latex, showing the evolution of a certain variable in 5 experiments (number can vary). THe experiments are named "pX". Each experiment is characterized by 3 attributes. My question is the following one: **how to write the attributes of each experiment in the figure caption automatically?**

This information should be found either in a table OR either in 4 separated vectors. Both options are shown below.

```
Exp   Atribute1   Atribute2 Atribute3
p1       X11        X12      X13
p2       X21        X22      X23
p7       X31        X32      X33
p9       X41        X42      X43
p14      X51        X52      X53  

\def \lexperim{1, 2, 7, 9, 14} 
\def \latrib1{X11, ..., X51}
\def \latrib2{X21, ..., X52}
\def \latrib3{X31, ..., X53}
```

In order to automatize the figures, I define this command:

```
\newcommand\fig[1]{
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{center}
       \centering
       \captionsetup{justification=centering}
       \includegraphics[scale=0.45, keepaspectratio]{figures/#1-vari1.eps}
       \includegraphics[scale=0.45, keepaspectratio]{figures/#1-vari2.eps}
       \caption{Temporal evolution of the variable 1 for #1. HERE IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO PUT THE ATRIBUTES ASSOCIATED TO EACH EXPERIMENT} 
        \vspace*{-10pt}
       \label{fig:#1}
   \end{center}
\end{figure}
}
```

Then, I am doing a loop on the number of experiments.

```
\foreach \nexp in \lexperim{
    \fig{p\nexp}
 }
```

This works fine but, as said before, I would like to put the attributes of that experiment in the caption. For that, there are two options:

1. Go into the table, get all the attributes associated to the experiment and put them in a string together with their units. This option is the most convenient to me. However, I have not been able to find anything, perhaps because it is rather complex (especially to a beginner like me). Therefore, I would also be happy with the second option.
2. Detect the position of the experiment pX in the vector \lexperim (let's imagine that this position is k) and get the k component of the vectors \latrib1 \latrib2 \latrib3. As far as I can see, this simple action is not straightforward in Latex. Therefore, I would also like to know if you recommend me embedding code from other tool into Latex to deal with such issues.

I would be glad to read your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can offer an `expl3` interface.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_iggt_experiments_prop % save attributes
\seq_new:N \g_iggt_experiments_seq   % save experiment IDs
\tl_new:N \l__iggt_experiments_table_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\addexperiment}{mmmm}
 {% #1 = experiment ID, #2 - #4 = three attributes
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_iggt_experiments_seq { #1 }
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_iggt_experiments_prop { #1@1 } { #2 }
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_iggt_experiments_prop { #1@2 } { #3 }
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_iggt_experiments_prop { #1@3 } { #4 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\experimenttable}{o}
 {% #1 = nothing or list of IDs
  \tl_clear:N \l__iggt_experiments_table_tl
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 } { \__iggt_experiments_all: } { \__iggt_experiments_list:n { #1 } }
  \__iggt_experiments_print:
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printexperiment}{m}
 {% #1 = experiment ID
  Experiment\nobreakspace#1:~
  \prop_item:Nn \g_iggt_experiments_prop { #1@1 },~
  \prop_item:Nn \g_iggt_experiments_prop { #1@2 },~
  \prop_item:Nn \g_iggt_experiments_prop { #1@3 }.
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__iggt_experiments_all:
 {
  \seq_map_function:NN \g_iggt_experiments_seq \__iggt_experiments_addrow:n
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__iggt_experiments_list:n
 {
  \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \__iggt_experiments_addrow:n
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__iggt_experiments_addrow:n
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l__iggt_experiments_table_tl
   {
    #1 &
    \prop_item:Nn \g_iggt_experiments_prop { #1@1 } &
    \prop_item:Nn \g_iggt_experiments_prop { #1@2 } &
    \prop_item:Nn \g_iggt_experiments_prop { #1@3 } \exp_not:N \\
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__iggt_experiments_print:
 {
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
  \toprule
  Exp & Attr1 & Attr2 & Attr3 \\
  \midrule
  \tl_use:N \l__iggt_experiments_table_tl
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\addexperiment{p1} {X11}{X12}{X13}
\addexperiment{p2} {X21}{X22}{X23}
\addexperiment{p7} {X31}{X32}{X33}
\addexperiment{p9} {X41}{X42}{X43}
\addexperiment{p14}{X51}{X52}{X53}

\begin{document}

\experimenttable

\bigskip

\experimenttable[p1,p7,p14]

\bigskip

\printexperiment{p2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Addition

Here's how you can do the loop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% a command for loops
\NewDocumentCommand{\foreachcsv}{mm}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 } 

% the specific part
\prop_new:N \g_iggt_experiments_prop % save attributes
\seq_new:N \g_iggt_experiments_seq   % save experiment IDs
\tl_new:N \l__iggt_experiments_table_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\addexperiment}{mmmm}
 {% #1 = experiment ID, #2 - #4 = three attributes
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_iggt_experiments_seq { #1 }
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_iggt_experiments_prop { #1@1 } { #2 }
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_iggt_experiments_prop { #1@2 } { #3 }
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_iggt_experiments_prop { #1@3 } { #4 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\experimenttable}{o}
 {% #1 = nothing or list of IDs
  \tl_clear:N \l__iggt_experiments_table_tl
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 } { \__iggt_experiments_all: } { \__iggt_experiments_list:n { #1 } }
  \__iggt_experiments_print:
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printexperiment}{m}
 {% #1 = experiment ID
  Experiment\nobreakspace#1:~
  \prop_item:Nn \g_iggt_experiments_prop { #1@1 },~
  \prop_item:Nn \g_iggt_experiments_prop { #1@2 },~
  \prop_item:Nn \g_iggt_experiments_prop { #1@3 }.
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__iggt_experiments_all:
 {
  \seq_map_function:NN \g_iggt_experiments_seq \__iggt_experiments_addrow:n
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__iggt_experiments_list:n
 {
  \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \__iggt_experiments_addrow:n
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__iggt_experiments_addrow:n
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l__iggt_experiments_table_tl
   {
    #1 &
    \prop_item:Nn \g_iggt_experiments_prop { #1@1 } &
    \prop_item:Nn \g_iggt_experiments_prop { #1@2 } &
    \prop_item:Nn \g_iggt_experiments_prop { #1@3 } \exp_not:N \\
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__iggt_experiments_print:
 {
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
  \toprule
  Exp & Attr1 & Attr2 & Attr3 \\
  \midrule
  \tl_use:N \l__iggt_experiments_table_tl
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% three lines commeted out just for the example
\newcommand{\experimentfigure}[1]{%
  \begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
%    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
%    \includegraphics[scale=0.45, keepaspectratio]{figures/#1-vari1.eps}
%    \includegraphics[scale=0.45, keepaspectratio]{figures/#1-vari2.eps}
    \caption{Temporal evolution of the variable 1 for #1. \printexperiment{#1}}
    \label{fig:#1}
  \end{figure}
}


\addexperiment{p1} {X11}{X12}{X13}
\addexperiment{p2} {X21}{X22}{X23}
\addexperiment{p7} {X31}{X32}{X33}
\addexperiment{p9} {X41}{X42}{X43}
\addexperiment{p14}{X51}{X52}{X53}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\experimenttable

\bigskip

\experimenttable[p1,p7,p14]

\bigskip

\printexperiment{p2}

\section{Figures}

\foreachcsv{p1,p14}{\experimentfigure{#1}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works! However, I have two issues: first of all, I have tried to integrate the function     printexperiment{p2} in the loop and it puts me an empty string. How can I import this function into the loop? The second thing that I would like to ask is where I can find information about the syntax that you have used. I am a beginner and I do not understand many of the things that have been used. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @IGGT The language used is `expl3` and you find several instances of it on the site. Do `texdoc expl3` and `texdoc interface3` for more information. I added a simple loop macro.